# Find a solution to the differential equation: Which is NOT a constant multiple of the solution given.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

Find a solution to the equation:
$$
ty'' - (t+1)y' + y =0
$$
Which is not a constant multiple of the solution: $y(t) = e^t$.

---

Hi, I have worked this problem and have solved it, using the particular solution of $e^t$. Why is this problem asking for a solution that is not a constant multiple of the only given solution? I do not see another way of solving it

Thank you!

---

(*solution from comment*)

Using reduction of order we aim for finding $y_2$ based on the solution given. In this case $y(t) = e^t$ is a solution. Following that we have $y_2 = g(t)  y_1$. $G$ is an unknown and will eventually be substituted for $u = g'$. Following this we differentiate $y_2$ to get $$y_2' = g_1'  e^t + g_1  e^t.$$ We differentiate again for $$y_2'' = g_1''  e^t + 2g_2'  e^t + g_2  e^t.$$ Next, we substitute $y_2$, $y_2'$ and $y_2''$ into the given equation and also substitute $u=g'$ to get $$tu' +2ut -tu -u =0.$$ Solve this equation by separation and then integrate and get the solution of y_2. We find the last $y_2 = t+1$.

Comment: Would you be so kind to outline your solution and what you find unsatisfying with it? Did you perform order reduction using $y(t)=e^tu(t)$?

Comment: Show that $y_1=e^t$ and $y_2=-1-t$ are Solutions,

Comment: Sure. using reduction of order we aim for finding y_2 based on the solution given. In this case y(t) = e^t is a solution. Following that we have y_2 = g(t) * y_1. G is an unknown and will eventually be substituted for u = g'. Following this we differentiate y_2 to get y_2' = g_1' * e^t + g_1 * e^t. We differentiate again for y_2'' = g_1'' * e^t + 2g_2' * e^t + g_2 * e^t. Next, we substitute y_2, y_2' and y_2'' into the given equation and also substitute u=g' to get tu' +2ut -tu -u =0. Solve this equation by separation and then integrate and get the two solutions. We find the last y_2 = t+1.

Comment: I suppose you have shed light on it for me! I am still confused because the solution itself contains a constant multiple of e^t. I have solved it but am not sure why is asking for a solution that is not a constant multiple of itself.

Comment: Please add additional insights directly to the question, it is better readable and in context. I did this for the previous comment, please edit for style or other insights. What exactly is your question now? $1+t$ is not a constant multiple $ce^t$ of the other solution.

Comment: Done. I have edited for a more concise question.

Comment: You have to meditate somewhat more on the meaning of "constant" in "constant multiple". It just means what it means, the task is asking for a non-trivial, independent second solution.

Comment: You should turn your edit into a proper answer down below.  It works better for the site that way (and it would get upvoted).

Comment: Related post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866006/reduction-of-order-leads-to-non-elementary-integral.

Answer (score 3):

Write $$ t(y''-y') = y'-y$$

Now let $z=y'-y$, then $${z'\over z} = {1\over t}$$

so $$ \ln z = \ln t+ c\implies z = a\cdot t$$

for some real $a$. Now you can try if $y$ can be linear $y=kt+n$:

$$ k-kt-n = at \;\;\; \implies \;\;\; k=-a\;\;\wedge \;\;n=k=-a$$

so $y= -at-a$ is solution for every real $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ty'' - (t+1)y' + y =0$$
$$ty'' - ty'-1y' + y =0$$
$$ty'' -y'-( ty'-y) =0$$
Divide by the integrating factor $\mu(t)=t^2$
$$\frac {ty'' -y'}{t^2}-\frac {( ty'-y)}{t^2} =0$$

$$(\frac {y'}t)'-(\frac yt)' =0$$
Integrate

$$\frac {y'}t-\frac yt =K_1$$
$$(ye^{-t})'=K_1te^{-t}$$
Integrate again
$$ye^{-t}=-K_1(t+1)e^{-t}+K_2$$
$$\implies y(t)=C_1(t+1)+C_2e^t$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way we could go is by power series. Letting $y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^k,$ we have: $$\begin{eqnarray}ty''&=&t\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)a_kt^{k-2}\\&=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k+1)ka_{k+1}t^k\end{eqnarray}\tag{1}$$ $$\begin{eqnarray}(t+1)y'&=&(t+1)\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kt^{k-1}\\&=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kt^k+\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kt^{k-1}\\&=&a_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kt^k+\sum_{k=2}^\infty ka_kt^{k-1}\\&=&a_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(ka_k+(k+1)a_{k+1}\right)t^k\end{eqnarray}\tag{2}$$

Putting this into the given equation, we have $$0=a_0-a_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left((k+1)ka_{k+1}-ka_k-(k+1)a_{k+1}+a_k\right)t^k,$$ or $$0=a_0-a_1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(k-1)\left((k+1)a_{k+1}-a_k\right)t^k.$$ Consequently, we must have $a_0-a_1=0,$ and for all $k\ge 2,$ we must have $$(k+1)a_{k+1}-a_k=0.$$ Put another way, we must have $a_1=a_0,$ and for $k\ge 2,$ we must have $a_{k+1}=\frac1{k+1}a_k.$ Thus, all of the coefficients are completely determined by the values of $a_0$ and $a_2,$ since by an easy inductive argument, we have for all $k\ge2$ that $$a_k=\frac2{k!}a_2.$$

Thus, we have $$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^k=a_0(1+t)+2a_2\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k!}t^k,$$ and so $$y=a_0(1+t)+2a_2\left(e^t-1-t\right)=(a_0-2a_2)(1+t)+2a_2e^t=c_1(1+t)+c_2e^t.$$ Thus, a particular solution that is not a constant multiple of $e^t$ is (for example) $t+1.$